Automatic signing failed
I have added an additional capability called "User Assigned Device Name" into my application. Since then we are facing issues on code signing. We are trying to Sign in Automatically and getting the below error always.
/.xcodeproj Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com..*******" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.contacts.notes entitlement.
Actually contact notes entitlements are not a part of our additional capabilities as we requested separately with Apple and received it in the provisioning profile long back. Actually that time the same(contacts notes entitlements) was not a part of the additional capabilities. Please advise if any one has gone through such a conflict and resolved.

I don't think you can do automatic signing for apps with additional capabilities. (At least, this used to be the rule.)
